# How do I get the body in a SOAP response when I have a ClientTransportException

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

In SoapUI/Postman I am sending this request
[image: Image describing the request]
Notice how I am getting a 401 Unauthorized, but I am getting a response body. The 401 is expected.
Now I am trying to send this message with jax-ws. I intercept the messageresponse with a handler.
My handler looks like this:

```
public class SHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> GetHeaders");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext) {
        boolean isRequest = (Boolean) soapMessageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (!isRequest) {
            try {
                System.out.println(soapMessageContext.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getValue(););
            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Message");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext) {
        try {
            System.out.println(soapMessageContext.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getValue());
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> HandleFault");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> Close");
    }
}
```

I would expect to get a return value from the request, but I get null. I only see this response in my console:
`com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized` 
How do I get the body that is shown in the Postman request?

Some more context information:
The jax-ws service that makes requests to the blurred out endpoint

```
@WebServiceClient(
        name = "LIReceiveMessageService",
        targetNamespace = "http://uic.cc.org/UICMessage",
        wsdlLocation = "src/main/java/nl/rls/ci/soapinterface/UICCCMessageProcessingInboundWS.wsdl"
)
public class LIReceiveMessageService
        extends Service {
    ....
}
```

The messageResolver I added using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-soaphandlers.htm#i268373) oracle guide.

```
LIReceiveMessageService service = new LIReceiveMessageService();
service.setHandlerResolver(new MyHandlerResolver());
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `handleMessage` method you can add the following

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(stream);
String messageBody = new String(stream.toByteArray());
```